# Decoding multiple JSON records

Tags: php

I have a text file with a number of JSON records in it. Is there a simple way, using PHP to decode the records. Example:

```
{
   'id':1
}

{
   'id':2
}
```

Comment: Are there the empty lines between jsons ?

Comment: Yes, there are empty lines between the individual JSON records

Comment: Valid JSON uses quotation marks and not single quotes. Please bear this in mind when trying to use `json_decode`.

Comment: Then read line by line adding to string and decode when empty lline is read

Comment: As @vsharper points out, this isn't even valid JSON. You need to revisit how you're generating this text file in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I realize it uses quotation marks. This is a manually constructed example, and my editor went wild. And no, it's not a file I am generating, it's a file I inherited. Yes, I know I can count empty lines, it was a stab in the dark to see if there's a simpler solution out there.

Comment: Use a regex split/double linebreak detector, and PEAR JSON_Services to decode JSOL-style expressions.

Comment: no, there's no automated tool/function in php that can slurp in a file and parse out multiple separate chunks of json. that's something YOU will have to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is **only one** empty line between each JSON block of data, then next code would work, it process each line of file, if empty line is read, one block of JSON data has finished and it is displayed, then continues with the rest :

```
<?php
$arr = file( "data.json" ); // READ WHOLE FILE AS ARRAY OF STRINGS.
$block = ""; // STORE ONE "BLOCK" OF JSON DATA.
foreach ( $arr as $line ) // PROCESS EACH LINE IN FILE.
{ if ( strlen( $line ) > 2 ) // IF LINE CONTAINS MORE THAN LINEBREAK.
       $block .= $line; // STORE LINE.
  else { // EMPTY LINE FOUND (LINE WITH LINEBREAK ONLY, 0D,OA).
         $json = json_decode( $block );
         print_r( $json );
         echo "<br/><br/>";
         $block = ""; // CLEAR BUFFER FOR NEXT BLOCK OF JSON DATA.
       }
}
// PRINT LAST BLOCK OF JSON DATA.
  $json = json_decode( $block );
  print_r( $json );
?>
```

Tested with this file :

```
{ 
  "id":1
}

{ 
  "id":2
}

{ 
  "id":3
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do get some valid json data in there, you can do the following

```
  <?php
        $data = rtrim(ltrim(file_get_contents('file.json')));
        $json_objs = explode("\n",$data);
        if(count($json_objs)){
              foreach($json_objs as $json_obj){
                     //do something
              }
        }else{
              echo 'No json objects found in file';
        }
  ?>
```